# Is it possible for an immune host to be reinfected and show symptom before swift recovery?

Tags: immunology

For example, let's say the pathogen is a virus, and the host was infected once but recovered purely on its own and thus retained a highly effective adapted immunity.
However, if we IV inject the the host with an overwhelming dose of virus, is it possible to infect some cells, cause some cell death before the immunity taking over and the host recovery? Is it possible to completely overwhelm the immune system and kill the host anyway?